# need an application switcher

Tags: windows

ive got a touch screen jukebox.  i also have some shadow dancer movies.  what i would like to do is find a program where i can have the jukebox and VLC running at the same time.  when the screen is idle for say 5 minutes, it brings VLC to the front (identical to an alt+tab) and when the screen is touched it does another alt+tab to bring the jukebox back to the front.  im sure its easy enough to write, but its been forever since ive done a windows program and was wondering if it already existed or not

Comment: You're specifically asking how to do it *without* writing software. This isn't software development related.

Answer (score 1):

There are programs out there that'll do that, but most of them are obscure, old, and pretty much useless.

Spending a couple hours learning the basics of a scripting language like Autohotkey and write a quick script with the help of the command reference is what I would do.

Comment: +1 for AutoHotKey, exactly what I came here to recommend